# How to open popup with dropbox-api dropbox-js V2

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I'm trying to migrate to dropbox-api v2 in my web application.
Currently I have implementation of opening popup window where user connects to his/her dropbox and I get token. Which I use to get access to files user selected in Dropbox.chooser in later steps.

But I'm having hard time to find the solution for this. I have link to all migration documents dropbox has, but there is not any word about what is the equivalent of client.authenticate() and Dropbox.AuthDriver.Popup() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common Dropbox!!! I just found this issue posted in GitHub for dropbox-sdk-js, and the answer that they don't have this functionality in V2 :( it is really disappointing, i need to implement all staff myself:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/73#issuecomment-247382634

**Updated**

I have implemented my solution and would like to share if someone will need.

To open a popup window I use following code:

```
window.open(dropbox.getAuthenticationUrl("MY REDIRECT URL"), 'DropboxAuthPopup', 'dialog=yes,dependent=yes,scrollbars=yes,location=yes')
        
window.addEventListener('message',function(e) {
   if (window.location.origin !== e.origin) {
       // Throw error
   } else {
       // e.data Is what was sent from redirectUrl
       // e.data.access_token is the token I needed from dropbox
   }
},false);
```

Then on my page, which I specify dropbox to redirect, i put:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var message = parseQueryString(window.location.hash)
    window.location.hash = '';
    
    opener = window.opener
    if (window.parent != window.top) {
        opener =  opener || window.parent
    }
    
    opener.postMessage(message, window.location.origin);
    window.close();

})
```

Example of parseQueryString can be found from [dropbox-sdk-js examples](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/master/examples/javascript/utils.js)